# What kind of game maps can I use with SpriteKit?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, sprite-kit

I am building an OS X game using Swift and the SpriteKit framework. **I don't know, what kind of game map I should use in the project.** I started with a .sks file and it might work, but seems too time-consuming.

Screenshot of my crude .sks map.:

[image: sks map image]

I need to have access to the position of the solar system nodes so I can center the map on any of them. I need to hide parts of the map. Also, I need to be able to get the angle between solar systems.

On a small scale, I could make this work with the .sks, but I am going to add maybe around a hundred solar systems, so individually placing solar system nodes and struggling with shape nodes to form the lines between the solar systems is simply ridiculous.

This is my first game map, so I am completely oblivious to the different kinds of file types and applications I could use to make the map.

Comment: If you completely oblivious on how to do any of this, perhaps you are reaching to far right now. Start small and work your way towards this project. You should already know what positions your nodes are as you are the one adding them. As for centering a node in the view and finding the angle between 2 points, a simple google search will give you the answers. Your question is also too broad in its scope.

Comment: I think, you have misunderstood me. Of course, I know the positions and angles between nodes. The point was to learn about other ways to create a map of my game world. I don't want to use a .sks file for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a database (NSArray? NSDictionary?) of solar systems. Each entry in the db would have all information for that solar system (name, coordinates, planets, moons, etc.). Warping between solar system would change which entry is used to redraw the screen, etc. (Note: NSArrays and NSDictionarys can be easily loaded and saved to (text editable!) XML files.)